# How to find files added/deleted/modified within the last X days using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to know if it's possible to create a powershell command that works like InstallRite?

http://installrite.software.informer.com/

In InstallRite, you can create a snapshot, install an application, and then compare the current environment with the snapshot to determine which files and registries have been added/deleted/modified.

I intend to use this for forensics so I can easily identify which files have been added/deleted/modified in the last X days.

Comment: deleted is deleted, you cant, for created or modified you can whith filter where in gci command

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$Nbdays=10
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file | 
    where {$_.CreationTime.Date -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Nbdays).Date -or $_.LastWriteTime.Date -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Nbdays).Date}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll play with both LastWriteTime and CreationTime. Is there an equivalent command for querying added/modified registry entries?

Comment: Sorry, but i did not downvote. I am new to stackoverflow so I need at least 15 points to cast a vote. I actually find your answers useful.